# Can't connect to my Oracle Virtual Cloud Instance

Tags: oracle, ssh, cloud

the Terminal just says:

```
ssh: connect to host xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 22: Connection timed out
```

[Here are the firewall rules.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJKF3.png)

I can't ssh into the VM so I cant change the firewall rules on the VM

Please Help.

Answer (score 1):

First, double-check your IP address: it must match your [Oracle Virtual Cloud Public IP Address](https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/Network/Tasks/managingpublicIPs.htm#Public_IP_Addresses), assuming it is a reserved one (meaning it is a fixed one)

Second, check your *local* firewall: you cannot change the remote ones, but the local rules might still block your SSH traffic.

As [mentioned here](https://community.oracle.com/tech/apps-infra/discussion/4131540/unable-to-ssh-into-baremetal-instance):

> ust by opening the port through firewall and security lists will not allow new incoming connections. Ex: unless there is a service listening on port 443 (Tomcat etc), you will be unable to connect. Same with SSH daemon for port 22.

So make sure the SSH daemon is up and running.

Check also [Default Security List](https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/Network/Concepts/securitylists.htm#ariaid-title4)

> Unlike other security lists, the default security list comes with an initial set of stateful rules, which should in most cases be changed to only allow inbound traffic from authorized subnets relevant to the region that homes that VCN or subnet.
>
> A list of authorized subnet ranges relevant to each region can be found [here](https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/iaas/tools/public_ip_ranges.json) .

In particular:

> **Stateful ingress**: Allow TCP traffic on destination port 22 (SSH) from authorized source IP addresses and any source port.
>
> This rule makes it easy for you to create a new cloud network and public subnet, launch a Linux instance, and then immediately use SSH to connect to that instance without needing to write any security list rules yourself.

Comment: The IP is ok, and I can ssh into my other servers. Just the Oracle servers have a problem.

Comment: @TheJakobCraft OK. I have edited the answer with more suggestions.

Comment: As seen in my screenshot, the firewall rules for TCP 22 are allowing connections. But how should I start the SSH daemon if I can't even connect?

Comment: @TheJakobCraft Not sure, beside contacting their support. Can you try with another new Oracle instance, for testing?

Comment: so it seems that I'm an idiot and I don't know how to setup Virtual Cloud Networks. I looked up for a guide and created a new network. Now it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can mount your machine drive to some other machine, edit sshd config and mount it back.

That helped me :D

See this ref: https://blogs.oracle.com/cloud-infrastructure/post/recovering-opc-user-ssh-key-on-oracle-cloud-infrastructure